# Отключение обработки события onclick

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть таблица с 2 элементами при нажатии вы3ывается функция randomImg

```js
function randomImg(id) {
  if (stateGame === 'imgClosed') {
    document.getElementById(id).src = '' + img[gameImg[id]] + '';
    stateGame = 'imgOpened';
    imgOne = gameImg[id];
    idOneImg = id;
    return;
  }
  if (stateGame === 'imgOpened') {
    document.getElementById(id).src = '' + img[gameImg[id]] + '';
    imgSecond = gameImg[id];
    idSecondImg = id;
    if (imgOne === imgSecond) {
      //Условие чтобы onclick ольше не отрабатывался
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><img id="0" src="style/img/images.png" height="150" width="102" onclick="randomImg(0) " /></td>
  <td><img id="1" src="style/img/images.png" height="150" width="102" onclick="randomImg(1)" /></td>
</tr>
```

При вызове функции изначальная картинка меняется на картинку из массива по id и если первое id === второе id мне надо чтобы событие onclick при нажатии на элементы таблицы больше не отрабатывался

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687790/how-to-remove-onclick-with-jquery

Comment: а на js можно это как то реали3овать? я еще не ра3бираюсь в jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```
elem.onclick = null
```

В данном случае, `elem` это элемент по которому кликнули

Comment: if (cardOne === cardSecond) {
     idOneCard.onclick = null;
idSecondCard.onclick = null;
    }
Так ? я только параметр id передаю при вы3ове. Как  еще определять элемент по которому кликнули ?

Comment: Указывайте вторым аргументом параметр `event` вот так: `function randomImg(id, event) {..}` - внутри функции уже используйте `event.currentTarget` - это и будет элемент, на котором произошло событие. По другому, можно не указывая этого аргумента, написать внутри функции `window.event.currentTarget` - по сути будет то же самое)) Подробнее можете прочитать тут - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: Я сделал так`document.getElementById(idOneImg).onclick =  null;
                    document.getElementById(idSecondImg).onclick =  null;`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cardOne === cardSecond){
   document.querySelectorAll('.js_click').forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('onclick') )
}
```

document.querySelectorAll('.js_click') - js_click любой css селектор